# Database Mail works in Production but not in Test Database

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-mail

I have a Production database that is able to send mail. And a Test that is not able to. They are both on the same SQL Server. The error is (SQL Server 2008):

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 1
>   EXECUTE permission denied on object 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

I am an intern and have no previous experience with SQL server (just SQL DML, DDL). I tried to debug this by looking at the permissions of the 2 databases but they are the same. So I don't even know how people can send mail from the production.

I looked online and in order for users to be able to send mail they have to be a user under msdb and have the DatabaseMailUserRole. In my case it's a Windows domain. What's funny is that this domain isn't there, so how is production sending mail? I also tried putting the domain there as a user and gave them the permission, but still no luck for the test database.

How do I determine why/how the production database is able to send mail, so that I can debug? Thank you, I would appreciate any help.

Let's say it's too complicated to debug and I want to copy the production database to the test database (as an exact duplicate), will all permissions carry over?

Comment: The error is telling you that you dont have appropriate permissions in msdb database.

Comment: So you mention that there is a user, but without a domain. That sounds to me like a SQL user--not windows user. I would verify that first. Because you may not even have your windows user added at all yet. Then, compare both mail profiles between test and prod.

Comment: How do I compare mail profiles, where are the "directories/files" of interest. Why do you think that one of them can send and not the other?

Comment: is database mail activated on the sql server as a whole or on a per database basis?

Comment: @Kin I said in my post that I added the windows domain to the msdb users and gave them the DatabaseMailUserRole, so doesn't that mean they have the permission?

Answer (score 0):

To send Database mail, users must be a user in the `msdb` database and a member of the `DatabaseMailUserRole` database role in the `msdb` database.

To add `msdb users or groups` to this role use SQL Server Management Studio or execute the following statement for the user or role that needs to send Database Mail.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'DatabaseMailUserRole'
    ,@membername = '<user or role name>';
GO
```

Source: Microsoft docs  [Permission denied on sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms188719(v=sql.105))